# Get Box iOS app url scheme parameters for a web app

Tags: ios, box-api, url-scheme, iphone-standalone-web-app

Is it possible for a web app to make use of the `box`:// url-scheme with parameters to open a specific file in the Box `iOS` app?

The `Android` Box app has a similar function with its intent links.

And if it is possible, what would these parameters be? (already using Oauth2 API to list files with shared links).

Answer (score 1):

`boxopendirect://file?id=<fileid>` to redirect to a file.

`boxopendirect://folder?id=<folderid>` to redirect to a folder

Answer (score 0):

It certainly is possible to open other apps from inside a webapp using a proprietary scheme identifier. Unfortunately, you will need to know the exact scheme syntax in advance. There's a good list of them available here:

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

For example, to open the youtube app directly, you can use:

```
youtube://
```